# how many datatables can creates in data set in sql?

Tags: sql-server, datatable, dataset

In sql server , How many data tables can creates in Dataset?

Is there any limit to define data tables in dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your memory. Apart from that it's only limited by [Int32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx). So `2^32` is the maximum number of `DataTables` you can hold inside a `DataSet`(**2,147,483,648** tables, happy coding).

By the way, a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) can contain **16,777,216** rows, but that's not what you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size is limited by Int32 is 2^32, since Tables.Count property will return you an integer value.

Eg:
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
int count=ds.Tables.Count;//it will give the total number of tables in your dataset.

Also, the maximum number of rows that a DataTable can store is 16,777,216.